# Rails Installer the system can not get the specified path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed rails and ruby with railsinstaller. The problem is, when i run rails command, it gives me: "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tried uninstalling rails and installing it againt, does not help. Ruby commands executes like "ruby -v", "rails -v" doesn`t work.

Have googled,didn`t find solution for windows, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your system PATH variable.

To do this go to 
`My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables`

Click PATH and add the path to Ruby, which will be along the lines of `C:\ruby\bin`